# Computing $\pi_1(\text{Pr}(S),\mathbb{P}_0)$

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $(S,d)$ be a complete separable metric space, and consider the space $\text{Pr}(S)$ of probability measures on $S$ that are defined on Borel sets arising from the metric $d$. Now endow $\text{Pr}(S)$ with the topology of weak convergence of measures (say, by putting the Lévy-Prokhorov or bounded Lipschitz metric on $\text{Pr}(S)$).

I'm wondering what's known about the fundamental group of this space. However, it's not even clear to me that $\text{Pr}(S)$ is path-connected. Does anyone know of any references on this sort of topic?

Edit: I know that $\text{Pr}(S)$ is a convex subset of the space of all finite Borel measures on $S$, and so I think $\text{Pr}(S)$ should be path connected and even have a trivial fundamental group. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: suffices to check $tP(\cdot)+(1-t)Q(\cdot)$ is a prob. measure. But the interesting part is that by Krein-Milman the extremal points are the Dirac measures and that they are w*-dense in Pr(S).